# Give 2 users folder permissions only works periodically

Tags: server, 18.04, permissions

I have a weird issue with folder permissions on my ubuntu server.

I have 2 users which need access to nginx logs, `www-data` (nginx) and `dd-agent` (datadog, a logging service).

I created a group `logusers` and added both users to that group, then I changed permissions as follows:

`sudo chown -R dd-agent:logusers /var/log/nginx/`

I can see the following for `ls -l`:

> drwxr-xr-x    2 dd-agent  logusers           4096 May 29 06:25  nginx

Then I check both the status of the dd-service and nginx-service, and both are fine, but after a couple of hours, datadog reports a permission denied error for opening a file inside /var/log/nginx/.

How can I make sure both users have proper access? Why does this change over time?

--Edit:
Restarting the `datadog-agent` service and checking its status again shows no permission errors. This is weird.

Comment: has that file been newly created, probably with different rights? have you checked `ls -la /var/log/nginx/specific-file`

Comment: I don't understand why you create a new group to do that. Why don't you add the users to the `www-data` and `dd-agent` groups?

Comment: @AlexOnLinux Indeed is has been. `-rw-r-----  1 dd-agent logusers 118883 May 29 09:25 access.log`

Comment: Also remind : newly created files in `/var/log/nginx/` (after the `chown`-command) will not be associated with the group`logusers`.

Comment: @mook765 So `sudo usermod -a -G www-data dd-agent` and  `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/nginx/` should do it right?

Answer (score 0):

if you want your new created files to be created as the group you specified to the folder you could do the following

```
sudo chmod g+s /var/log/nginx/
```

this will set the SGID-Bit ( Set Group ID ) to the folder with the result that every new created file inside that folder will inherit the group of the folder.